# Python XLSX file manipulation issue

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, openpyxl

I have a problem I cannot fix :

The workflow

- Code 1 generates an XLSX file containing a sheet (with data)
- Code 2 process this output file,
  a) creates a new sheet with some calculations
  b) creates graphs based on these calculation, (Matplotlib)

The problem :

- Code 1 generates the initial workbook 'output.xlsx' OK
- When I run Code 2, the new sheet is created but it only contains headers. The graphs are not created.
- I manually delete this new sheet and re-save 'output.xlsx'
- When I run Code 2 a secpmd time, the new sheet is created again and this time data is calculated, and graphs are created.

So basically what is required here is to run Code 2 once, delete the sheet, and rerun it to make it work.
I do not understand it. 
I am soliciting help to fix this. (I am a beginner).

Thanks

Code 2 :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl

# Charger le fichier Excel
nom_fichier = "output.xlsx"
classeur = openpyxl.load_workbook(nom_fichier)

# Charger les données depuis le fichier Excel
df = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx', sheet_name='Feuil1')

# Filtrer le DataFrame pour ne prendre en compte que les lignes avec une valeur dans la colonne 'HVC_CT_CORR'
df = df.dropna(subset=['HVC_CT_CORR'])

# Créer un DataFrame avec les résultats agrégés par TRIG
resultats_df = df.groupby('TRIG').agg({
    'HVC_CT_CORR': 'sum',
    'JOURS': 'sum',
    'J_PRESENCE': 'sum',
    'FONC': 'first',
    'QUAL': 'first',
}).rename(columns={'HVC_CT_CORR': 'Total_HVC'}).reset_index()

# Convertir la colonne 'QUAL' en chaînes de caractères
resultats_df['QUAL'] = resultats_df['QUAL'].astype(str)

# Ajouter une nouvelle colonne pour le compte du nombre de lignes par TRIG
resultats_df['Nombre_Lignes'] = df['TRIG'].value_counts().reset_index()['TRIG']

# Ajouter une colonne supplémentaire "Moy_Mens"
resultats_df['Moy_Mens'] = (resultats_df['Total_HVC'] * resultats_df['JOURS'] / resultats_df['J_PRESENCE']) / resultats_df['Nombre_Lignes']

# Enregistrer le résultat dans un nouvel onglet du fichier Excel en mode 'append'
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    # Charger le fichier Excel existant
    writer.book = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
    # Ajouter le DataFrame à la feuille existante
    resultats_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Resultats', startrow=0, startcol=0, index=False, header=True)

    # Créer un graphique différent pour chaque QUAL
    for qual in resultats_df['QUAL'].unique():
        qual_df = resultats_df[resultats_df['QUAL'] == qual]

        # Trier les valeurs de FONC dans l'ordre INS, CDB, OPL, puis par ordre alphabétique du TRIG
        qual_df = qual_df.sort_values(by=['FONC', 'TRIG'])

        # Identifier les 15% des valeurs les plus hautes et les plus basses
        quantile_low = qual_df['Moy_Mens'].quantile(0.15)
        quantile_high = qual_df['Moy_Mens'].quantile(0.85)

        # Créer un graphique à barres
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
        ax = plt.gca()

        # Utiliser une liste de couleurs
        colors = ['skyblue' if trig_value >= quantile_low and trig_value <= quantile_high else 'cornflowerblue' for trig_value in qual_df['Moy_Mens']]

        # Ajouter les étiquettes directement sur les barres et les annotations pour les TRIG dans les 15% les plus élevés et les plus bas
        for i, (trig_value, fonc, trig) in enumerate(zip(qual_df['Moy_Mens'], qual_df['FONC'], qual_df['TRIG'])):
            color = 'skyblue' if trig_value >= quantile_low and trig_value <= quantile_high else 'cornflowerblue'
            bar = plt.bar(i, trig_value, color=color)
            plt.text(i, trig_value, f'{trig_value:.2f}', ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=8, color='black', rotation=90)
            
            if trig_value <= quantile_low or trig_value >= quantile_high:
                plt.text(i, trig_value, f'{trig}', ha='center', va='top', fontsize=8, color='red', rotation=90)

        plt.axhline(qual_df['Moy_Mens'].mean(), color='green', linestyle='-', linewidth=2, label='Moyenne')
        plt.axhspan(qual_df['Moy_Mens'].mean() - qual_df['Moy_Mens'].std(), qual_df['Moy_Mens'].mean() + qual_df['Moy_Mens'].std(), alpha=0.2, color='yellow', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1, label='Moyenne ± écart type')

        plt.xticks(range(len(qual_df)), qual_df['FONC'] + '-' + qual_df['TRIG'], rotation=45, ha='right')
        plt.xlabel('FONC-TRIG')
        plt.ylabel('Moyenne Mensuelle')
        plt.title(f'Répartition de Moy_Mens pour QUAL={qual}')
        plt.tight_layout()

        # Enregistrer le graphique dans un fichier PNG
        graphique_filename = f'graphique_{qual}.png'
        plt.savefig(graphique_filename, format='png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5)

    # Enregistrer les modifications dans le fichier Excel
    # writer.save()

# Afficher les résultats
plt.show()
```